# API Gateway Resource Policy to Prevent Deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm looking to write a resource policy on an API that can prevent a resource from being deleted/modified by other tenants in my account. From the documentation, the only examples of resource policies I'm finding are to govern invoking the API, not managing resources.

Is this possible to accomplish with a resource policy?

Comment: Api gateway has a really bad naming / design in regards to this. Are you talking about the so-called resources within one api? Or are you talking about invoking a DELETE http endpoint from a user or are you talking about the AWS resource that is your actual api gateway?

Comment: I'm talking about managing resources within an API, not invoking an endpoint. Glad to hear I'm not the only one critical of the naming!